# How to generate auto meta tags in ASP.NET pages for SEO with Dynamic Year

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, meta-tags

I have my company website in .NET, I want its meta tags like Title and Description auto updated when the year change, like it was "Top SEO Consultants in 2021" now I want it should be automatically  "Top SEO Consultants in 2022" when year change. Please can you share code in .NET Core for dynamically changing the year?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

`<meta name="description" content="Top SEO Consultants in @DateTime.Now.Year">`